# How to install a Canon printer without software drivers or connecting to wifi on Mac

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, drivers, printing, printer

I am look at [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201900) which basically says you can simply configure your printer from the printer LCD screen by entering the wifi password and boom you're done. This means you don't have to install any drivers which I would like to avoid. However, I'm not sure about the [security of giving the printer your wifi password](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/200562/security-implications-of-attaching-a-wireless-printer-to-network), so I wanted to see if there's a way to install a printer on a Mac using a USB cable, which doesn't require using a software driver/installation. That is, I would imagine there is *some* printer where you simply plug it into your Mac and it shows up in some settings panel and you can simply open a PDF in Preview and press "Print to X printer", and you would get all of this without having to install drivers or connect through wifi. Or if this is not possible I'd be interested to know why. I'd also be interested to know if [connecting to USB is a security risk](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/200564/security-implications-of-connecting-to-a-printer-via-usb), but that's a separate question :). Basically, I don't want to connect the printer to the network at all, just directly connect to it via USB. I haven't found anything instruction-wise saying how to do this or if it's technically possible. If it is, I don't see why they're trying to sell you on downloading and using the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of separate parts to your question.

First, yes there is a minor security risk by connecting the printer via WiFi. However, that risk exists for every device that is connected, be it your Mac, your TV or your fridge. At least your printer will not attempt to access the internet via the router - your TV or fridge will.

That risk does not exist when using a USB or wired network connection. Both of these also have the advantage that they are a lot more reliable than WiFi. Unlike laptops, printers do not recover gracefully from WiFi dropouts.

Now, as to the need for a driver. As @Mawg pointed out, you **always** need a driver to print; even a blank page requires a driver. However, in most cases OSX does make your life easier, as it is supplied with drivers for a huge number of printers. Most printers can be installed simply by plugging it in (or setting up the printer's WiFi connection). OSX will "see" the printer and either install the driver, or prompt you to get it. That is probably what happened with your earlier printers. If this does not work with your current printer, please start by telling us the exact model, and someone will check driver availability.

Answer (score 1):

What ake you think that "This means you don't have to install any drivers"?

A driver is necessary to to instruct the printer - it tells it how to print.

Even a blank page with a single red dot in the centre needs to send instruction to the printer about how & what to print.

All printers speak a different language, and it's the driver that tells them what to do, in that language.

Short answer - you can't do what you think you can. It doesn't work like that.

cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver

Footnote: some Operating Systems, such as Windows come with a few built in printer drivers for the more popular makes of printer. I don't know about mac, but 1) I am presuming you already tried that & there was not such a built in driver or you would not be asking here, and 2) you would still have a driver. No driver = no talking to the printer.

If in doubt, contact your printer manufacturer.

Comment: This is not correct somehow. I have definitely used printers where I just plugged in a USB and it showed up in my settings and I pressed print. I didn't have to install a driver or anything. It sounds like this is built into the Mac somehow, automatically having it work with any printer. But I'm not sure how it works or how to do it. Likewise, Canon makes you install their "camera driver" for DSLRs to get it working, but it turns out you can just use iPhoto or Lightroom and don't even need the driver at all, Mac picks it up automatically.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, I have a few other questions first.

Comment: Yes, I agree (+1). As you were posting that, I updated my asnwer. Good luck, but probably best ask your manufacturer. Happ New Year :-)